# Xamarin AAR Binding. Some classes are not included into binding

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

I made C# binding for my **AAR** library, but fragments that extends **Support Fragment** are not included into binding. Also method from other classes that have **return type** of **Support Fragment** also are not included.

My inheritance hierarchy: **ScreenAFragment ( *public* )** -> **PermissionsRequesterFragment ( *public abstract* )** -> **BaseFragment ( *public abstract* )** -> **Fragment ( *android.support.v4.app package* )**

Could anyone point me to a reason for this behavior and also tell my how to add these fragments to binding?

Comment: Check the build **warning** of your binding library for issues concerning those classes (Did you add the Support v4 package to your binding library?)

Comment: @SushiHangover I added support v4 from NuGet to my binding. warnings says top ancestor ScreenAFragment no found for nested type ScreenAFragment.[and number here] (there is around 14 warnings like that with different number after [classname.] ). As I understood from api.xml all these classes with numbers are definition of anonymous classes used inside that fragment but there is no actual fragment definition in api.xml

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: @SushiHangover I already read this gist, no help was found there :(

Comment: You have two things going on most likely. 1. You need to include the proper reference jars to your binding. They need to be the exact version that the library was created with. You can check this by looking at the `build.gradle` file of the library module. 2. If there are signs of obfuscation, you need to use metadata transformations to "deobfuscate". https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#missing-types--obfuscated-types

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Xamarin and I haven't found a solution for this issue.

But I made a workaround by creating **Static Factory** that returns **java.lang.Object** in every method like **getScreenAFragment(...), getScreenBFragment(...)** etc. So client could get **Object** object and cast it to appcompat **Fragment**. This workaround satisfies the requirements for my library use and could be helpful for someone.

***If u know how to deal with that issue please post ur answer and if it works I will accept it.***